# cannot add existing page to Facebook App

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-apps, facebook-page

We run a website with a blog and we're using a wordpress plug-in that pushes the blog posts to facebook via an app.  It is working fine for regular users but we want it to push the posts to the organisation's community page.
The annoying thing is, I deleted an existing community page and created a new page via the "Create New Facebook Page" button in the "App Page:" setting of the "App Details" area for my app.
The new page was created exactly as requested, and it still won't allow me to link it to the app.

How can I get this working?

The Wordpress plug-in is called "Add Link To Facebook" in case anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you are using the pro version and confirm this. It seems this functionality is only provided in pro.

Wordpress requires a separate action to authorize pages. So using an app for example you'll first authorize your account to be accessed and then another popup will appear asking you to select one of many pages in your account. Is anything like this happening?

Comment: Regardless of the plug-in and wordpress - shouldn't the page that I just created, via the link that facebook gave me, using the instruction facebook gave me, be able to added as the App Page?...